# How to wait for a list of threads to finish? (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

For a single thread, I would do

```
thread.join(60)
threadEvent.set()
```

How can I make it wait for all threads in the list to finish OR wait until the timeout and then issue the set() to the threading.Event()? Each thread has a corresponding threading.Event() that will be used to stop the thread. The important part is that if the timeout is reached, I need to set the event for each thread.

Comment: Keep a list of threads and their corresponding events?

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887346/synchronising-multiple-threads-in-python?

Comment: Basically it doesn't matter if you don't join a thread as soon as it's finished - so you can wait for one of the threads, then another, with a timeout of the remaining overall timeout time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time
endTime = time.time() + 60
for t in threads:
    t.join(endTime - time.time())
    t.event.set()
```

Comment: Probably with a loop over the events? Since each thread has its own event?

Comment: @Douglas Leeder Oops, overlooked that. Moved the event setting in the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what join() with a negative timeout does. Maybe it would be bad?